# bootstrap navigation active links not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my navigation active on the active div, the following example shows and hides the correct divs but doesn't add the active class to the link:

HTML

```
<div class="list-group" id="admin-list"> 
<a href="#add-user" data-toggle="tab" class="list-group-item"> Add a user </a> 
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#nav li a").on("click", navigation("#nav li"));

$("#admin-list a").on("click", navigation("#admin-list a"));

var foo = function(navigation) {
    $(navigation).removeClass("active"); //Remove any previously "active" li
    $("#home, #about, #contact", "#add-user").hide(); //Hide all "pages"
    $($(this).prop("href")).show(); //Show only the current target
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Set click a as active
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies within

```
($(this).prop("href")).show();
```

Because that is not a valid selector. If you are just trying to get the current link just reference it like this:

```
$(this).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two things I did... I commented out the prop href show line, and removed the .closest and I'm finding that active is now properly being added as a class to the a tag.

Here's the fiddle I was using:

http://jsfiddle.net/LWAmE/

(I didn't add bootstrap as I didn't need to in order to test the code out)

```
$("#admin-list a").on("click", function(f){
f.preventDefault();

$("#admin-list a").removeClass("active"); //Remove any previously "active" a
$("#home, #about, #contact, #add-user").hide(); //Hide all "pages"
//$($(this).prop("href")).show(); //Show only the current target
$(this).addClass("active"); //Set click a as active
});
```

Comment: after seeing Thunda's comment, I went back and looked at it, and realized that the problem had to do with the $($(this).prop("href")).show().  $(this).closest('a').addClass("active") does in fact work, but you don't need the closest part.

Comment: I've updated my question as I actually use this for two navigations on the same page. It works fine for the first one but not the second..

Comment: did you mean navigation("#nav li") or foo("#nav li")?